# Specify only the second parameter in a javascript function

Tags: javascript

[The spec for the jQuery `ajax.error` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is:

```
error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)Function
```

I'm trying to catch the error and display the `textStatus`, but I can't figure out how to specify only the `textStatus` without having to put in a variable name for `XMLHttpRequest` and `errorThrown`.  My code currently looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: hbAddressValidation.webServiceUrl,
    data: this.jsonRequest,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5,
    success: function (msgd) {
         //...
    },
    error: function (a,textStatus,b) {
        $("#txtAjaxError").val("There was an error in the AJAX call: " 
                                + textStatus);
    }
});
```

You can see in my code that I'm putting variables `a` and `b` as placeholders for the first and last variables in the `error` function.  I know that in my success function, I'm only providing one parameter and it works fine, but in that case `data` is the first parameter.  In the case of `error`, `textStatus` is the *second* parameter, but that's the only one I want to specify.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The closest that you can get is:

```
error: function (a,textStatus) {
    $("#txtAjaxError").val("There was an error in the AJAX call: " 
                            + textStatus);
}
```

Only the last parameters can be omitted

Answer (score 4):

After programming in Erlang for a while, I started using "_" as the name of a variable that I don't care about. It's just a convention like anything else but it clarifies situations like that for me. Javascript seems to be OK with using "_" for more than one parameter, I think.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to, you can use the `arguments` array:

```
error: function () {
    var textStatus = arguments[1];    //Zero-based
    $("#txtAjaxError").val("There was an error in the AJAX call: " 
                            + textStatus);
}
```

However, it's a horrible idea; you should simply add an unsused parameter.

Comment: I agree with the "horrible idea" part :-)